# ２次元配列の最後尾の指定の仕方

Tags: julia

Juliaにおいて、２次元配列の最後尾の指定の仕方はあるのでしょうか？（自分が調べた限りではなさそうです）

```
array = zeros(Int64,3,3)
array[2,:]=[1,1,1]
array[3,:]=[2,2,2]
```

の２次元配列があるとして、最後尾をコピーしたい場合

```
a = copy(array[3,:])
```

ではなく、もう少し一般化して書きたいということです。
例えば配列指定にlength(array)を使うなどです。
少し投げやりな質問になってしまいましたが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`end`で一番最後が指定できます。

`array[end,:]`

Answer (score 0):

今、自分が考えたものでは、配列の列を変えなけらば、

```
div(length(array),3)
```

で、最後尾の指定ができそうです。